# How to push view controller on click of HyperLink in Swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

Hi I have to push a viewController on click of HyperLink. I have NSMutableAttributedString text. that attributed text have two hyperlink examples  **GoToHomeScreen** and **aboutUs** both are hyperLink on click of **aboutUs** need to open a link which is working fine

```
    let attributesString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "GoToHomeScreen for know more about app and for info aboutUs ")
    attributesString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://apple.com/aboutUs", range: NSRange(location: 50, length: 7))
    textFields.isEditable = false
    textFields.delegate = self
    textFields.attributedText = attributesString
```

to open aboutUs working fine but how can we push a view controller on click of GoToHomeScreen

Note:- I am using UITextView to perform it, I can't use button

Comment: Add a custom link like "myApp://goToHomeScreen", and implement UITextViewDelegate method `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`, detect the link, if it's a custom one (for aboutUS), push VC and return `false` in that method, else return true (let normal behavior, like opening Safari.app).

Comment: is GoToHomeScreen text is the link ?

Comment: @RajaKishan yes GoToHomeScreen is link as a text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add also a link for GoToHomeScreen.

```
attributesString.addAttribute(.link, value: "myApp://GoToHomeScreen", range: ...)
```

Since you have already set the delegate, implements `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

    if URL.absoluteString == "myApp://GoToHomeScreen" {
        pushHomeScreenVC()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Nice solution @Larme.  Another delegate method I need to try to remember!